# some windows in i3wm look weird

Tags: arch-linux, gtk, i3

I use Arch Linux with i3WM. In i3 some of the windows and their menus look fine but in applications like Eclipse and Transmission, it makes weird unseparated tool bars.

This image looks fine:
[image: good screenshot]

but not this one:
[image: bad screenshot]

There is no such an issue in Ubuntu (+ i3wm). Any solutions?

Comment: GTK update: your theme is broken...

Comment: I found new version of the theme. it fixed the issue. post comment as an answer please!

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks for re-correction of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent [GTK 3.20 update](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointNineteen/ReleaseNotes) has broken a lot of themes; until such time as they are updated to work with the new API, you will need to use a standard theme (like Adwaita) that is compatible with the new version.